Topkis lattice theorems for strong Nash equilibria?
Apologies in advance if my question is unclear. A well known result of Topkis is that, in short, the set of Nash equilibria of a supermodular game is non-decreasing. Is there an equivalent result for strong Nash equilibria, i.e., if the set of strong Nash equilibria of a supermodular game is non-empty, then it is non-decreasing?
